Azure DevOps Test pass rate data not showing
I have an Azure DevOps .yaml pipeline that executes some .Net tests created using XUnit.
The test are executed with the following command
--collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --results-directory "./coverlet" --logger "trx;logfilename=testresults.trx" --configuration Release

and this is the .yaml task that publishes the results
- task: PublishTestResults@2
      displayName: Publishing test results
      inputs:
        testResultsFiles: 'coverlet/**/*.trx'
        testResultsFormat: 'XUnit'
        failTaskOnFailedTests: true

From the logs, I see that the testresults.trx file has been generated and that the publish of the results went well.
However, when I open the Analytics tab for the pipeline I executed, I cannot see the data in the Test pass rate area, but the Pipeline pass rate and the Pipeline duration information are displayed correctly.
Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Notes
I'm using Azure DevOps server 2022


I cannot see the data in the Test pass rate area, but the Pipeline pass rate and the Pipeline duration information are displayed correctly.

If you cannot see the data in the Test pass rate area, it could happen when there's no test executed in pipeline or pipeline result is NOT published.
Please go to the pipeline run result page, check if there's a Tests tab as below, it shows all the tests executed in the current run. If the tab exists, you should be able to see data in Test pass rate report.

If the Tests tab doesn't exist, go to the test task log, check if there are any test executed actually.

If the test is executed in the test task, please check if you publish the test result. Suppose you are using DotNetCoreCLI@2 task(if not, use it), the task will automatically publish the test result by default, and automatically append the --results-directory {{Agent.TempDirectory}} in command. Hence, need to remove --results-directory in command to avoid conflict, sample as below:
jobs:
- job: job1
  steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet test
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      arguments: '--configuration Release --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --logger "trx;logfilename=testresults.trx"'
      publishTestResults: true                    #<- default is true
      testRunTitle: 'testruntitletest'
      #workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\XUnit.Coverlet.Collector'

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: Publishing test results
    inputs:
      testResultsFiles: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/*.trx'
      testResultsFormat: 'XUnit'
      failTaskOnFailedTests: true



Many thanks, with your help I solved the problem. I was using this for executing the tests
- script: |
          dotnet test ${{ parameters.solution }} ${{ configuration.arguments }} --configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}

Using the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task now I can see all the stats.

Glad to know it helps! Happy coding!
